# custom javascript buttons is not working in lightning

Tags: custom-button, lightning-experience

We have some Custom JavaScript buttons in my Salesforce org , we are planning to migrate from classic to lightning experience but i have noticed that custom JavaScript buttons are not working in Lightning experience.
What is alternative solution for this?

Comment: use lightning component in actions

Comment: please add your code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration).  Javascript buttons do not migrate over to the Lightning Experience.  You need to go over this trailhead module and find the best solution to replace your javascript button.